# Edit city and state name in Magento checkout

Tags: magento

I have a specific issue in my Magento checkout for customers in Germany. The issue is with special characters. For example ü. I want to edit the state and city to Ludwigsburg, Baden-Wurttemberg without the special u. The problem is that my shipping program doesn't accept non english characters. Anyone know where this is located?

Answer (score 0):

To change the translation of city and state for  germany go 
to  app->locale->de_DE(Germany locale)->Mage_Checkout.csv find 
city and state change your translation and flush your cache from admin..

Comment: I do not see a Mage_Checkout.csv in that folder